# What Service Account Does GKE Use to Access GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, google-iam

One of the Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters (`$GKE_CLUSTER`) within a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project (`$GCP_PROJECT`) seems to be **unable** to `pull` Docker Images from Google Container Registry (GCR):

```sh
kubectl config current-context

#=>

$GKE_CLUSTER
```

and:

```sh
kubectl get pods --namespace=$NAMESPACE

#=>

NAME        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE 
. . .       . . .   . . .              . . .      . . .
$SOME_POD   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          1m
. . .       . . .   . . .              . . .      . . .
```

and:

```sh
kubectl get events \
--field-selector involvedObject.name=$SOME_POD \
--namespace=$NAMESPACE

#=>

LAST SEEN   TYPE     REASON    OBJECT          MESSAGE
. . .       . . .    . . .     . . .           . . .
1m          Normal   BackOff   pod/$SOME_POD   Back-off pulling image "$SOME_IMAGE"
. . .       . . .    . . .     . . .           . . .
```

Where:

- `$SOME_POD` is of the form: `deployment-replicaSet-pod`
- `$SOME_IMAGE` is of the form: `us.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT/name:tag`

Listing only service accounts for `$GCP_PROJECT` gives:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $GCP_PROJECT \
--filter="serviceAccount" \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="value(bindings.members.split(':').slice(1:).flatten())"

#=>

XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
XXXXXXXXXXXX@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com 
XXXXXXXXXXXX@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com  
service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com  
service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@dlp-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com    
service-XXXXXXXXXXXX@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
PPPPPPPPPPPP@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Which of these service accounts is GKE using to access Docker Images hosted by GCR?

Comment: Compute Engine default service account is used by default when you create a new cluster.

Could you provide more information about the error you're facing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the specific error because by handing around enough permissions it was solved. The error was that a repository did not exist or not permissions to it. I verified it existed

Answer (score 9):

Each GKE node has an IAM Service Account associated with it. By default, nodes are given the Compute Engine default service account, which you can find by navigating to the IAM section of the Cloud Console.

If you are using the non default Compute Engine service account you probably will need to grant the service account roles/storage.objectViewer role in the project. Check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster) for more information.

Comment: For better accuracy about custom node service account.The role `storage.objectViewer` must be set on project scope. Specifying it on underlying GCR bucket doesn't work (as for `imagePullSecrets`).

Answer (score 6):

Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) doesn’t access Google Container Registry (GCR) directly: one or more node pools associated with the GKE cluster push and  pull Docker images through the Container Registry API,  authenticated and authorized through service accounts.

If your GKE cluster has a *single* node pool:

```sh
gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--format='value(nodeConfig.serviceAccount)' \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE

#=>

default
```

If your GKE cluster has *multiple* node pools:

```sh
gcloud container clusters describe $GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE \
--format='value[delimiter="\n"](nodePools[].config.serviceAccount)'

#=>

default
not-default@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com
. . .
```

default  here is the “Compute Engine default service account”: `$GCP_PROJECT_ID-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

**Note**: default serv. acct. differ from serv. acct. that you are able to create: beginning with a number and ending in a domain other than: `@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

In order for a serv. acct. to be able to `pull` Docker images from GCR it needs to have at least one associated role with the following associated permissions:

- `storage.objects.get`
- `storage.objects.list`

You might encounter:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [$GCP_PROJECT_NAME] or it does not exist.

if the serv. acct. does **not** have at least one associated role with the following associated permissions:

- `resourcemanager.projects.get`
- `resourcemanager.projects.list`

The curated role that contains all four of the above permissions is the `roles/storage.objectViewer` role.

If you ever want to store Docker images in another GCP project, you just need to grant the serv. acct. used by the node pool(s) within your GKE cluster the `roles/storage.objectViewer` role in the project your would like to store the Docker images (more on that [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-single-docker-repository-with-multiple-gke-projects-1672689f780c)).

**Note**: you may wish to use GCP Artifact Registry (AR) going forward.  More on transitioning from GCR to AR [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr).

Answer (score 2):

For GKE you will have an account ending like this "container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com" if you have any issue (that could be related with some changes over the API) you can remove the default accounts for GCE and GKE (Under "Name" you will see the details and which belongs to each resource) and re enable the service using the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable) to re-create your default service accounts, if not just assign the "Editor" role and try again.